# Individual particles and physics in Sprite Kit

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, sprite-kit, particles, skemitternode

I am a long time user of Stackoverflow but first post.

My question is seemingly simple, is there a way to make particles from an emitter interact with the physics sprites in the scene? (For example, if I am using a particle for rain, and I want it to bounce or bumpy off a sprite of a man with an umbrella. There must be a way, but I don't see a lot of documentation on adding physics to individual particles. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No.  There is no way to make SpriteKit's built in particles interact with physics bodies.  Every particle property you can control is a property of `SKEmitterNode`, and it has no properties for setting physics behavior for particles.

The fact is that particles are designed to be very light-weight so that you can have thousands of them on any hardware supported by SpriteKit.  Physics simulation is not light-weight.

Comment: Fair enough. it was worth the hope :) It definitely could make particles unwieldily if they can do everything a normal sprite can do. Thanks!

Comment: I have a question that any help would be greatly appreciated, if I really want to make an effect like my particles have physics, can I add my particles to a transparent image and use emitterNodes.targetNode = self property so can use transparent image's physic to detect any collisions & contacts?

Comment: If you have a question, click the “Ask Question” button (at the top right) and post a new top-level question.

Answer (score 0):

There is LiquidFun, which is a Box2D extension that simulate the physics of a particle system. This engine is the basis for Apple Spritekit physics engine and you can use it in your game but you have to tweek it a little bit to make it run. There are a lot of tutorials of how to use it in an ios project. I am confident that Apple will have more features added to Spritekit in the future that make the particle system respond to physics.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a SKField to simulate gravity and then another field on your umbrella to repulse it.